# Select and move SVG shapes using Web Speech APi

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using Web Speech API to manipulate SVG Shapes using JavaScript. I can manage to speak commands and make the shapes appear on screen but the problem is I don't know how to select and move the shapes using voice commands.

Example: How to able to select the shape ID and then speaking commands to move left,right, up, down.

The JavaScript Code below:

```
var counter = 0;

function buildCircle(x, y, colour) {
    if (buildCircle) {
        getElementById = "counter";
        counter++; // Increment the ID by 1 when a new shape is created
    }
    var f = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
    f.setAttribute("id", counter);
    f.setAttribute("cx", 350);
    f.setAttribute("cy", 350);
    f.setAttribute("r", "40");
    f.setAttribute("fill", colour);
    f.setAttribute("fill-opacity", "0.4");
    f.setAttribute("stroke", colour);
    svgOut.appendChild(f);
}

function buildSquare(x, y, colour) {
    var f = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
    if (buildSquare) {
        getElementById = "counter";
        counter++;
    }
    f.setAttribute("id", counter);
    f.setAttribute("x", 200);
    f.setAttribute("y", 300);
    f.setAttribute("width", "80");
    f.setAttribute("height", "80");
    f.setAttribute("fill", colour);
    f.setAttribute("fill-opacity", "0.4");
    f.setAttribute("stroke", colour);
    svgOut.appendChild(f);
}

function buildLine(x, y, colour, id) {
    if (buildLine) {
        getElementById = "counter";
        counter++;
    }
    var f = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");
    f.setAttribute("id", counter);
    f.setAttribute("x1", 160);
    f.setAttribute("y1", 400);
    f.setAttribute("x2", "160");
    f.setAttribute("y2", "300");
    f.setAttribute("stroke", colour);
    f.setAttribute("stroke-width", 5);
    f.setAttribute("fill-opacity", "0.4");
    svgOut.appendChild(f);
}

function interpret(text) {
    var result = text.match(/(purple|red|green|blue|yellow|orange|black|pink).+(square|circle|line)/i);
    if (result) {
        switch (result[2].toLowerCase()) {
            case "square":
                buildSquare(
                    lastMouseEvent.clientX,
                    lastMouseEvent.clientY,
                    result[1]
                );
                break;
            case "circle":
                buildCircle(
                    lastMouseEvent.clientX,
                    lastMouseEvent.clientY,
                    result[1]
                );
                break;
            case "line":
                buildLine(
                    lastMouseEvent.clientX,
                    lastMouseEvent.clientY,
                    result[1]
                );
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML Code